# ASA 5510 Need to filter traffic log events to my iPhone

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa

For some reason I cannot update apps or download apps to any ios devices on my network (tried both iphone and ipads).  When I'm at home on my own network everything works fine.  This started about a week ago.  I've configured my iphone with a static IP address and even used 4.2.2.2 as my dns to rule out that the issue is with my DNS Server.

I'm looking at the SYSLOG in ASDM (Cisco ASA 5510) but Im not sure it is providing me enough info.  It seems to be showing ACL blocks on my public ip address, but not individual client IP's, so I can't see whats going on.

How can I setup a way to filter any incoming/outgoing traffic to my iPhone's static IP and try and troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Cisco CSC SSM has HTTP scanning.  It's been on for a year without any problems but it seems a recent update to the device has cause some problems with 80 and 443 traffic (noticeably on iOS devices).  I turned off HTTP scanning and everything is working fine now.

Cisco is aware of the problem and looking to see if it is an isolated issue or something bigger.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For temporary testing, I'd suggest setting up an additional `allow` rule above whatever the device is hitting now that's set to just the IP you're interested in, with the logging for that specific rule cranked up to a high severity.

Answer (score 1):

I see you probably identified the problem. But to answer a bit of your original question...

Under the Monitoring section of the ASDM, there is a logging tab. From there you can pull up the Real-Time Log Viewer. The Viewer allows you to Filter By just about anything. So, you can filter by IP address, VPN user, Port. There is also a 'Build Filter' option for creating more complex filters if you choose.